# howto prevent gedit always opening a new unnamed file when launched

Tags: gedit

Is there a way to prevent gedit from always opening a new "untitled" file when launched (at least when an other file name is passed either with Alt+F2 and gksudo)? It is borring to always have to click "don't save" for this null file with nothing typed in it.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug as you can see here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/796076 and it doesn't look like it will be fixed because apparently, GNOME developers don't want users to run any application as root.

A work-around is to use "gksu" (or "gksudo") twice, like this:

```
gksu gksu gedit /path/to/file
```

You can make an alias so you don't have to run this twice. To do this, open ~/.bashrc and add this:

```
alias gksudo='gksudo gksudo'
alias gksu='gksu gksu'
```

Then, save the file and run this to source the ~/.bashrc file:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alin. It was fixed as of 2013-03-16 in gedit 3.7: just after this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/796076/comments/43